# What is Non-Java code?

Tags: java, jvm

I was learning about *JVM* and met with this word which is stored in 'Java Native Stack' (a Runtime Data Area) during loading of .class file.
Non Java code is also called Native code, but i really don't understand what is it.

Comment: Read up on JNI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/)

Comment: Native code (or JNI) is how Java does foreign functions; in java you can declare a method as `native`. But, if you do, you must then link to compiled (for example, C/C++) code for your program to function. However, as implied by *foreign*, it could also be some other language that supports such a binding (see also [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-java code is code that was not coded in the Java programming language.  There are actually two kinds:

- Native code (e.g. written in C or C++) that implements Java methods that have been declared as `native`.  Native code is typically compiled to the native instruction set of the hardware, assembled into a shared library / DLL and loaded by the JVM in response to a `System` method call.
- JVM bytecodes that were produced by something other than a Java compiler.  There are compilers for other languages such as Scala, Lua, Python, C#, etc that generate bytecodes for execution on the JVM platform.